# Tag Helper Intellisense not working after upgrading from ASP.NET Core 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

After upgrading from [ASP.NET Core 1.0 to 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/). But the `Tag Helper Intellisense` does not work. What may be missing?:

**project.json**

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-ABCTest-6af8ade3-87ff-4468-a9ce-8bb69c696ab8",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.1.0-preview4-final"  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

`_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using myProj
@using myProj.Models
@using myProj.Models.AccountViewModels
@using myProj.Models.ManageViewModels
@using myProj.AspNetCore.Identity
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

The build works fine. The tag helpers also work but I have to hard code the attributes such as `asp-controller`, `asp-action`, `asp-for`, `asp-items` etc. It was working before I moved to ASP.NET Core 1.1

There is also a note just before the Wrapping Section of Eric Anderson's article [here](http://www.elanderson.net/category/net-core/) about intellisense related issue. Not sure if that is relevant here.

Comment: Do ou get any errors/warnings on build?

Comment: @DavidG No. The build works fine. The tag helpers also work but I have to hard code the attributes such as asp-controller, asp-action, asp-for, asp-items etc. I've added an update section in my post to provide more info. It was working before I moved to ASP.NET Core 1.1. I may be missing something.

Comment: Same issue in vs2015

Comment: Did you solve this? Same here

Comment: @snekkke The problem still persists.

Comment: I have the same problem, even worse because tag helper intellisense also doesn't work.

Comment: @witoong623 You may want to look into the suggestions posted here by users `@JasonSmith` and `@Alex` below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools.

You have it in dependencies, but you need to add it to tools also:

```
 "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },
```

Comment: Already tried, it didn't work.  can you tell me what SDK you're using in global.json?

Comment: "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"

Comment: just repeated again, created now project in VS2015, it was 1.0.1, converted it to 1.1.0 by updating all nugets, tag helper intellisense disappeared, because razor was deleted from tools, I added it back and it's working again.

Comment: but I think you should change to 1.1.0-preview3-final as @Jason_Smith said, it works not completely with 1.1.0-preview-final (Razor Tools).

Comment: @Alex Alex's suggestion worked for me. **NOTE** to other readers: for some other readers the solutions suggested by other users in this post may work as well depending on their individual cases.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I had to configure my project.json to get tag helper intellisense:
Notice the lines commented out -vs- their equivalent uncommented:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    //"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
        //"version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
        "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0"
},

"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    //"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
},
```

So, basically, both *Razor.Design and *Razor.Tools had to remain at 1.0.0-preview3-final.

Also note, as @Alex stated, you need to specify *.Razor.Tools in "tools" as well.
I hope this helps. It's bummer for sure.

Ninja Edit: Don't forget to build your project, for intellisense wont work until you do. Might have to close and re-open the files, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, the above did not fix my problem until I installed the Razor Language Services.  Everything is working OK now.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.RazorLanguageServices

Not sure if it is a requirement still but I also installed the razor tools.
It installed the Preview4-final as of 5/1/2017.

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools –Pre

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had targeted `net46`, then when I changed to `net461`, it works again.  I also add version and imports to package section too.

```
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "imports": ["portable-net45+win8"]
},
```